# Is there a way to pass part of inputs into function?

Tags: javascript, function

Suppose I have a function as this:

```
function test(a, b, c, d) {
...
}
```

Is there a way that I can pass my inputs into the function as follows:

```
test(a:1,c;2)
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn’t support passing function arguments by name. Are you looking for `test(1, undefined, 2, undefined)`?

Comment: you can do something like `function test(o={a:1,b:2,c:3, d:4 })` then call `test({a: 1, c:2 })`

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for your comment. I know that will work but I just want to know is there exist a way allowing me to pass certain inputs into function.

Comment: Thanks to both T4rk1n and huydq5000 answers! That works!

Answer (score 0):

Named values doesn't support in a function, you have 2 options:

- Pass undefined value to unused variable like test(1, undefined, 2, undefined)
- Modified the parameters as an object like test(obj) and use obj.a, obj.b,... to pass the values

Answer (score 0):

You can not as you exactly suggested, but you could have your function take an object with your arguments as fields.

Ex:

```
function test(myArguments) {
    if (myArguments.a) {
      // do something with myArguments.a
    }
    ...
}
```

Call as:

```
test({a: 1, b: 2});
```